# how to get parent's method where I used 'controller as' syntax in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Recently, I write angularjs using 'controller as' syntax.

code like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('appParentCtrl', function(){
     this.name = 'XL';
     this.sayName = function(){
         console.log(this.name);
   }
});

app.controller('appChildCtrl', function(){
     //how can I get the 'sayName()' method defined in the appParentCtrl ???
});

html:
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="appParentCtrl as appParent">
        <div ng-controller="appChild as appChild"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

so,  how can I get the 'sayName()' method defined in the appParentCtrl ???

Answer (score 0):

You should inject $rootScope into your child controller